# joinWith return null foreign key value

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

Need to select some field from 2 tables using `joinWith()` method. I have 2 tables: apartments and city.

**Apartments** table has cityId field and **city** table has 2 fields: id and value.

Something like this:

[image]

I want to select some fields from **apartments** table and via ***cityId*** field get name (***value***) of **city**.

Relations in **apartments** model:

```
public function getCity() {
    return $this->hasOne(City::className(), ['id' => 'cityId']);
}
```

Relations in **city** model:

```
public function getApartments() {
    return $this->hasMany(Apartments::className(), ['cityId' => 'id']);
}
```

In controller I build query using `joinWith()` method, but it not return ***city.value*** field.

```
$apartments = Apartments::find()->select('apartments.title, city.value')->joinWith('city')->all();
```

`print_r($apartments)` returns this:

```
Array ( [0] => app\models\Apartments Object ( [file] => [_attributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array ( [title] => Квартира 1 ) [_oldAttributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array ( [title] => Квартира 1 ) [_related:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array ( [city] => ) [_errors:yii\base\Model:private] => [_validators:yii\base\Model:private] => [_scenario:yii\base\Model:private] => default [_events:yii\base\Component:private] => Array ( ) [_behaviors:yii\base\Component:private] => Array ( ) ) [1] => app\models\Apartments Object ( [file] => [_attributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array ( [title] => Квартира 2 ) [_oldAttributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array ( [title] => Квартира 2 ) [_related:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array ( [city] => ) [_errors:yii\base\Model:private] => [_validators:yii\base\Model:private] => [_scenario:yii\base\Model:private] => default [_events:yii\base\Component:private] => Array ( ) [_behaviors:yii\base\Component:private] => Array ( ) ) [2] => app\models\Apartments Object ( [file] => [_attributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array ( [title] => Квартира 3 ) [_oldAttributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array ( [title] => Квартира 3 ) [_related:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array ( [city] => ) [_errors:yii\base\Model:private] => [_validators:yii\base\Model:private] => [_scenario:yii\base\Model:private] => default [_events:yii\base\Component:private] => Array ( ) [_behaviors:yii\base\Component:private] => Array ( ) ) [3] => app\models\Apartments Object ( [file] => [_attributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array ( [title] => Квартира 4 ) [_oldAttributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array ( [title] => Квартира 4 ) [_related:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array ( [city] => ) [_errors:yii\base\Model:private] => [_validators:yii\base\Model:private] => [_scenario:yii\base\Model:private] => default [_events:yii\base\Component:private] => Array ( ) [_behaviors:yii\base\Component:private] => Array ( ) ) [4] => app\models\Apartments Object ( [file] => [_attributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array ( [title] => Квартира 5 ) [_oldAttributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array ( [title] => Квартира 5 ) [_related:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array ( [city] => ) [_errors:yii\base\Model:private] => [_validators:yii\base\Model:private] => [_scenario:yii\base\Model:private] => default [_events:yii\base\Component:private] => Array ( ) [_behaviors:yii\base\Component:private] => Array ( ) ) [5] => app\models\Apartments Object ( [file] => [_attributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array ( [title] => Квартира 6 ) [_oldAttributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array ( [title] => Квартира 6 ) [_related:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array ( [city] => ) [_errors:yii\base\Model:private] => [_validators:yii\base\Model:private] => [_scenario:yii\base\Model:private] => default [_events:yii\base\Component:private] => Array ( ) [_behaviors:yii\base\Component:private] => Array ( ) ) )
```

I don't see ***city.value*** field in this response, but see ***city*** field without any value.

Can you help me? What is problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have the relations in the model yii automatically generated the joined values .
Try this code

```
$apartments = Apartments::find()->all();
foreach($apartments as $apartment)
{
   echo $apartment->city->value;
}
```

sorry if this is not what you meant!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$query = new Query;
$query->select(['apartments.title as app_title', 'city.value as city_val'])  
              ->from('apartments')
              ->join('INNER JOIN', 
                  'city',
                  'city.id =apartments.cityId'
                  ); 

    $command = $query->createCommand();
    $data = $command->queryAll();
```

Comment: That answer correct, but response in array format. Anyway, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In joinWith, you missed join 'on' fields, apartments.cityId and city.id

```
$apartments = Apartments::find()->select('apartments.title, city.value, partments.cityId, city.id')->joinWith('city')->all();
```